# How to split mySQL information to show in HTML columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to figure out a way to split mySQL rows into HTML columns.  I'm sorry if there is an easier way to ask this, but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have read through very many suggestions though none of them fit what I am looking for.
I understand it is very easy to just float the information left and allow it to stack by itself.  My problem is that I am showing information in a "card" form with two different sized cards and I would like them all to stack without gaps vertically.

For the purpose of showing this, I've given every card a number from 1-3.  Every card numbered 1 should fit in the first column, and so on. [example here](http://beta.mybattlereport.com/collective.php)

Normal floating left gives me something like this:

```
|1|2|3|
|4|5|6|
|7|8|9|
```

This is the correct way to display the information, but it leaves gaps where large cards are next to small ones like in the example.

if I use a foreach loop in the php with a table or divs, I get something like this:

```
|1|2|3|
-------
|4|5|6|
-------
|7|8|9|
```

Unfortunately, this is pretty much the same outcome.  The larger cards push down the row leaving a large gap where a smaller card is.

I also understand that after the first visibile row, the most recent divs could potentially be pushed farther down in one column rather than another.  for example, if column 1 has 6 'featured' or large cards, it would take 12 cards to fill the space beside it.  I'm not worried about this.

The basic, stripped down code that I have right now is this:

```
<div class="container">
    <?PHP
    $qry_questions = mysql_query("SELECT STATEMENT**");
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_questions)){
        $count++;
        /*GATHER INFORMATION*/
    ?>
        <div class="HTML-formatting-here-with-php-echos">
        </div>
    <?PHP
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Now I'm just trying to figure out if I can make a statement in php that basically says:
"if $count == 1, append this information into column 1, if $count == 2, append this into col 2, etc."

Is there any type of function that I can do to split this information like this and append the information without completely building a whole new row?

p.s.  I've tried array_chunk() without the proper outcome.

EDIT: Here is the while loop

```
<div id="collective">
    <div class="container"> 
    <?PHP
        //FIND THE QUESTIONS ASKED AND INFORMATION ON THEM
        $qry_questions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbr_qa_questions ORDER BY q_votes DESC" /* LIMIT 0, 10"*/);  //LIMIT 0, 20 - 20 being how many to show at a time
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry_questions);
        $max_col = 3;
        $count = 0;
        //START THE LOOPING
        while($q_row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_questions)){
            $q_id = $q_row['q_id'];
            $q_votes = $q_row['q_votes'];
            $q_answers = $q_row['q_answers'];
            $q_title = $q_row['q_title'];
            $q_description = $q_row['q_description'];
            $q_tags = $q_row['q_tags'];
            $q_user_id = $q_row['user_id'];
            $q_created = $q_row['q_created'];
            $q_modified = $q_row['q_modified'];
            $q_featured = $q_row['q_featured'];
            if($q_featured == 0){
                $q_status = "normal";   
            } else {
                $q_status = "featured"; 
            }
            //GET THE USERS USERNAME
            $qry_username = mysql_query("SELECT user_name FROM mbr_user_name WHERE user_id =                         '$q_user_id'");
            $q_user_name = mysql_result($qry_username, 0);
            //FIND THE USERS POINTS
            $qry_points = mysql_query("SELECT point_amount FROM mbr_qa_points WHERE user_id = '$q_user_id'");
            $q_user_points = mysql_result($qry_points, 0);
            //FIND OUT IF YOU FLAGGED IT
            $qry_flagged = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbr_qa_flagged WHERE q_id = '$q_id' AND user_id = '$user_id'");
            $flagged = mysql_num_rows($qry_flagged);
            if($flagged >= 1){
                $flaggedDiv = "<div class='q_flagged'> &nbsp; </div>";
            } else {
                $flaggedDiv = "<div class='flagInnapropriate'> &nbsp; </div>";
            }
            //FIND HOW MANY ANSWERS
            $qry_answers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbr_answers WHERE q_id = '$q_id'");
            $q_answers = mysql_num_rows($qry_answers);
            //FIND HOW MANY VOTES
            $qry_votes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbr_votes WHERE q_id = '$q_id'");
            $q_votes = mysql_num_rows($qry_votes);
            //GIVE EACH ENTRY A COLUMN NUMBER
            $count++;
            if($count >= 4){
                $count = 1; 
            } 
<div class="card <?= $q_status ?>">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="tag">
            <div class="title">Votes</div> 
            <div class="votes">
                <div class="number">
                    <?= $q_votes ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="plus">+</div>
        </div>
        <div class="question">
            <p><?= $count/* . $q_title*/ ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="elapsed">
            <?PHP

                $time_since = $q_created;
                $time_now = time();
                $timeElapsed = $time_now - $time_since;

            ?>
            Asked <?= elapsedTime($time_since) ?> ago by
        </div>
        <a class="profile" href="./profile.php?profile_name=<?= $q_user_name ?>">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img src="pieces/avatars/avatar.php?profile_id=<?= $q_user_id ?>&size=xsmall" />
            </div>
            <div class="userName">
                <?= $q_user_name ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="points">
                <?= $q_user_points ?>pts
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="answer">
            <div class="title">
                Answers
            </div>
            <div class="numAnswers">
                <?= $q_answers ?>
            </div>
            <div class="answersText">
                Answers
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bestAnswer">
            <div class="title">
                Best Answer
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <p>Need to get highest rated answer here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>   
                }
                ?>

            </div>
        </div>
```

The included newAnswerLayout.php is just the html formatting of each card.

ANOTHER EDIT:

I believe I just need to make three mySQL queries that select every nth row.  Yes, the IDs on the rows are unique, but there is a possibility that some rows will be moved to another table which will leave gaps.

What I'm thinking now is to query the table, pull every third row, place that in column 1 and so forth, starting at the first entry.

EDIT 3:
What I am looking for is to do a SQL query that grabs all of the information on every third row, starting on row 1, then I need to do another query of every third row, starting on row 2, then the same for row 3.

Comment: Question has ultimately been answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942812/how-to-select-every-nth-row-in-mysql-starting-at-n/13942972#comment19227487_13942972

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left;` in your file

```
   http://beta.mybattlereport.com/styles/global.css
```

line `82`
class container

EDIT :

**first:** those cards with numbers 1,2,3 they all have same class `card normal` so if you apply changes to one card it will aplly changes to all cards

**solution :** try using table instead of divs.

**second :** your cards are ordered like that

```
 card1 card2 card3  featured card , card1 card2 card3 featured card
```

**solution :** this can also be fixed by table and you order them
 1 column will be for card1
2 column will be for card2
3column will be for card3
and then you can use other table under this for featured cards or a div.

EDIT2>

your problem is in the sql to get those cards generated by number of cards and featured
you should order them first by featured and then by votes

try this

```
   $qry_questions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbr_qa_questions ORDER BY q_featured ,q_votes DESC" /* LIMIT 0, 10"*/);
```

the numbers 1 and 2 and 3 you are just giving numbers to each card . so i dont see any purpose from those numbers why you are making them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how this would help at all.  line 82, class container is the container for everything.  It has no need to float.  Also, In my carefully worded text above, it states that float left (no matter on what) does not give the desired outcome.

Comment: your site is floated , yes it was the container ,so by float left i see your site become good , give it a try and see

Comment: I have just tried floating the container to the left and it shows no changes.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome - I see there was a small bug with firefox.  Float:left did fix the alignment issue, though it did not fix my column problem.  If you scroll down and look at the cards, there should be 10 cards perfectly aligned with no gaps.

Comment: Also, Take a look at the card titles (in quotes) they will be numbered from 1-3.  Any with the number 1 should be in the left column, 2 in the center and 3 on the right.  When you scroll down, you can see that since there are featured cards, it makes the normal floated cards go to the wrong columns

Comment: if you share how you gather informations in your while loop i can see how it must look like

Comment: Unfortunately this just happened to be a coincidence.  I will eventually have hundreds of carsdsand featured/normal will actually be more random.  I have tried using a table with a for each loop but again, the desired results were not accomplished.  The large cards push the row and makes it too tall. So the small cards end up having a gap under them.

Comment: with table you fix the columns by their width so it will be no push

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21310/discussion-between-goodmood-and-ntgcleaner)

Comment: why don't you try resizing the size of cards. It will make them to look of same size and your layout may also not get disturbed.

Comment: no they are resized, all are same size just featured, but the wrong is he is oredering them by divs instead of table . lets fix it in chat instead of writing comments here , i invited you

Comment: Sorry I had to step out before I could accept chat.  I will post the while loop and even using tables would be difficult.  When I use a for each loop with a table, it still has to create new rows.  The new row then pushes anything else in the row.  The reason the cards are different sizes is because I want to have featured cards that a user can purchase with points they earn

Comment: share your while loop , and we see your code, like that it will be easy

Comment: Its a very long loop with variables that are needed to call other variables. I will share in the next 3-5 minutes when I have access to my computer. I'm currently on mobile

Comment: Edited with the while loop.  I am also in the chat that you created earlier.

Comment: you just posted the variables. where they are those generated `div`s ?

Comment: sorry i dont see any divs of those generated cards1 cards2 , featured.

Comment: they are at the bottom of the while loop.  It starts with <div class="card <?= $q_status ?>">

Comment: The "featured" and "Normal" cards will not have a listing hierarchy.  The featured cards will be mixed in with normal cards, the only reason for being featured is to make the card larger.  

Yes, I am currently giving the numbers 1, 2, 3 to every card, but that is just to show which columns they should technically be displayed in.